# Class Specification Description with charset/encoding latin1 iso-8859-1

Tags: character, uml, iso-8859-1, visual-paradigm

I’ve got Visual Paradigm version 16.3 (build 20211114 ) with OntoUML plugin version 0.5.3 and like to set the Class Specification Description charset to latin1/ iso-8859-1.
When I export one model to gUFO, the specific latin characters are lost.